# How to call javascript function from the $(document).ready(function())

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As you can see below I am trying to call the two functions after my document has loaded, however when I am running the code I get the following error: `syntax error unexpected token: <`

edit: I added my html code below so you can take a closer look at it. Thanks

this is my index.php file:

```
<?php
require 'fb-php-sdk/facebook.php';
$app_id = '251156051648844';
$app_secret = 'be37135d238e66ddce8f4ce8db20e668';
$app_namespace = '';
$app_url = 'http://www.paulmeskers.com/rutgers/twenty/canvas/';
$scope = 'email,publish_actions';

// Init the Facebook SDK
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
));

// Get the current user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Auth Dialog
if (!$user) {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => $scope,
  'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
));

print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['request_ids'])) {
  $requestIDs = explode(',' , $_REQUEST['request_ids']);
  foreach($requestIDs as $requestID) {
  try {
    $delete_success = $facebook->api('/' . $requestID, 'DELETE');
   } catch(FacebookAPIException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    }
  }
}



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Twenty Questions</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="ttt" />
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://apps.facebook.com/251156051648844/" />
</head>
<body id="yo">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui.js'></script>

<script>
    var appId = '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>';
    var uid;

    // Initialize the JS SDK
    FB.init({
        appId: appId,
        cookie: true,
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        uid = response.authResponse.userID ? response.authResponse.userID: null;
    });

function authUser() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
    uid = response.authResponse.userID ? response.authResponse.userID : null;
    }, {scope:'email,publish_actions'});

}


</script>


    <input type="button" id="b1" value="Create Game" onClick="createGame(uid)"/>
<input type="button" id="b2" value="Share this game" onClick="shareOnTimeline()" />
    <input type="button" id="b4" value="fetch created games" onClick="fetch_creator_games(uid)" />
    <input type="button" id="b5" value="fetch joined games" onClick="fetch_joined_games()"/>
    <input type="button" id="b3" value="tewst" onClick="build_creator_ui()" />

    <p><b>Games created by me:</b></p>
    <div id="createdGames" ></div>
    <p>------------------------------------------------------</p>
    <p><b>Games created by others:</b></p>
    <div id="invitedGames" ></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error looks like it is outside of this code block

Comment: Yea it's somewhere else.... do you get a line number when you run it in firefox?

Comment: I agree with John, is there any way you could post more code?

Comment: Yup.  Nuthin' wrong w/the code I see here.

Comment: error of an html tag , need to see more of ur code

Comment: the line number is in the jquery library: 
jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2U

Comment: There has to be more to the JavaScript than this. What is `inviterID`, and where is it defined? Where are the bodies to these functions?

Comment: @ Jonathan the code works fine with static html buttons and these functions, it is only when I use the document.ready code that I get this syntax error.

Comment: @WelfLudwig There is still code missing. Where are your opening and closing `<script>` tags? Where is `inviterID` being defined?

Comment: inviterID is a global variable in my javascript src, I will add the html code above

Comment: @WelfLudwig Where is your doctype, your opening HTML tag, or the script tags that surround this JavaScript?

Comment: @WelfLudwig Your JavaScript is above the `<!DOCTYPE html>` line? This will definitely break your page. See the HTML portion of my answer below.

Comment: no my javascript is below this

Comment: @WelfLudwig Post your code here as it exists on your machine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10868/discussion-between-jonathan-sampson-and-welf-ludwig)

Comment: If nobody's going to mention it, then I will. **Don't post your app secret id anywhere public or discoverable.** It's called an app `secret` for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere during the execution of your page a `<` character ended up where it shouldn't be. Since you suggested this error was being raised in the jQuery source file, it's likely that you have a selector written incorrectly. Perhaps you were trying to select an HTML element and forgot to wrap it in quotes, or you were trying to create an element.

#### Keep Your JavaScript Clean

This error could be raised by something that resembles the following:

```
$(<input>).attr("id", "foo");
```

Note the selector isn't wrapped in quotes, hence this will raise an error that reads like the one you received.

#### Check AJAX Responses

I noticed you are expecting JSON to come down the pipe, but after pushing some POSTS off to your server I found that an incorrect userid would result in the following response:

```
<br/><br/>
<label style='color:red;font-size:200%;'>
  Unable to load guessing games for user_id
</label>
<br/>
```

This could cause problems. Be sure to send your error messages down as JSON as well.

```
{ success: 0, message: 'Unable to load guessing games for this user id' }
```

To construct this JSON string in PHP, you can do the following:

```
$response = array( 'success' => 0, 'message' => 'Unable to...this user id' );
echo json_encode( $response );
```

#### Keep Your Markup Clean

Make sure you have a proper page as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!-- no whitespace or output before the doctype -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <style>
      body { color: red } /* styles in the head */
    </style>
    <script>var scripts_in_the_head_tag = true;</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>HTML goes within the body tags.</p>
    <script>var scripts_in_the_body_tag = true;</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically see this error when I make an ajax request that expects a JSON response, but receives HTML instead.